# How to convert LPT code to a sound file (e.g. WAV) using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sound-synthesis

I'm trying to synthesize a long term potentiation (LTP) code in Matlab that I can convert to a sound file. I have been able to synthesize a code but I need help parsing the code, and then converting it to a sound file.

Here is my current script:

```
fs_Hz = 48000; % sampling rate
ntrains = 3; % number of trains
npulses = 20; % number of pulses
pulsefreq_Hz = 100;
iti_s = 1.5;  % inter-interval train
amp_V = 10; % Amplitude in volts
pulsedur_s = 100e-6;  % pulse duration in seconds.
dur_s = iti_s * ntrains;
nsamps = ceil(dur_s * fs_Hz);
tt = [1:nsamps] / fs_Hz;
yy = zeros(nsamps, 1);
for tr = 1:ntrains
    t0 = (tr - 1) + iti_s/2;
    for pu = 1:npulses
        t1 = t0 + (pu-1)/pulsefreq_Hz;
        istart = round(t1 * fs_Hz);
        iend = istart + round(pulsedur_s * fs_Hz);
        yy(istart:iend) = amp_V;
    end
end
```

Comment: you mean to save it as a sound? which variable, `yy`? Google "Matlab save wav", just follow the first link

Comment: Yes, I want to save variable yy as a sound. Thanks.